# Unchecking a Previously Selected Checkbox when another checkbox is checked

Tags: vb.net

My form has 3 checkboxes available to the User. When the User mistakenly checks one Checkbox and realizes the mistake then checks the correct Checkbox, I need the incorrect checked Checkbox to Uncheck automatically.

I have diligently searched the web but have been unable to find any sites that offer answers for VB 2010. Mostly they provide solutions for HTML, Excel, Java, etc.

```vb
Private Sub BeginnerForm_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    StartupForm.Close()

    If Me.CheckBox1.Checked Then
        Me.CheckBox2.Checked = False
        Me.CheckBox3.Checked = False
    ElseIf Me.CheckBox2.Checked Then
        Me.CheckBox1.Checked = False
        Me.CheckBox3.Checked = False
    ElseIf Me.CheckBox3.Checked Then
        Me.CheckBox1.Checked = False
        Me.CheckBox2.Checked = False
    End If
End Sub
```

The results of this code is that it does not uncheck the Checkbox(es). I get no error code, it just does not UNCHECK the Checkbox(es). I have also tried other code entries such as `Me.Checkbox2.CheckState.Checked = CheckState.Unchecked` to no avail. Trusting you can steer me in the right direction to UNCHECK a Checkbox when another Checkbox is CHECKED.

Comment: You are using check-boxes as `radio buttons`. Why not change them to radio buttons instead and the behavior you are looking for will be done for you?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, as mentioned by daShier, you place the code in the wrong event handler. Since you want to uncheck the other checkboxes when one is being checked, you must put the code in the either `Click` or `CheckChanged` event handler of all your checkboxes that take part in this selection logic. I would suggest to put in the `CheckChanged` event since it will be triggered even when your checkbox check state is changed through code in addition to through mouse or keyboard actions.

```
' declare variable to keep track of the previous selected checkbox
Dim prevSelectedCheckBox As CheckBox

' all checkboxes to be controlled are handled by this event handler
Private Sub CheckBoxes_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CheckBox1.CheckedChanged, CheckBox2.CheckedChanged, CheckBox3.CheckedChanged
    ' first, identify which checkbox is triggering this event
    Dim this As CheckBox = DirectCast(sender, CheckBox)

    ' if this event is triggered when this checkbox is being checked
    If this.Checked Then
        ' if there is a checkbox previously selected/checked
        If prevSelectedCheckBox IsNot Nothing Then
            prevSelectedCheckBox.Checked = False ' uncheck it
        End If

        ' now this checkbox is currently the checked one, save it to the variable
        prevSelectedCheckBox = this

    ' if event is triggered by unchecking this checkbox, and this checkbox is the previously checked checkbox
    ElseIf this.Equals(prevSelectedCheckBox) Then
        ' clear the variable since now, there is no checkbox is being checked
        prevSelectedCheckBox = Nothing

    End If
End Sub
```

However, if user can only select one option among the options represented by the checkboxes, you better use radio button instead.

Comment: Thank you for your response ajakblackgoat.  Yes, my Users can only select one correct option.  My App is a Trivia game.

Answer (score 0):

It appears you are processing the code in the wrong handler. You are changing things when closing the form. Try moving the code to the `CheckBoxx.CheckedChanged` handlers:

```
    Private Sub CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CheckBox1.CheckedChanged
        If CheckBox1.Checked Then
           CheckBox2.Checked = False
           CheckBox3.Checked = False        
    End Sub
```

**UPDATE**: I realize that your original code that I copied and pasted would cause a loop since the changing of the checkbox states would trigger the other routines. It's not necessary since you only need clear the other boxes if the box your user is clicking is `checked`.
You will need to add similar code to `CheckBox2.CheckedChanged` and `CheckBox3.CheckedChanged` as well.

Also, I should point out that you are trying to make `checkboxes` act as `radio buttons`. Why not replace the checkbox controls with radio buttons instead so that VB handles the one-only behavior for you?

Comment: By the way: You can get to these handlers by simply "clicking" on the checkboxes on the design screen for your form. Visual Studio will create the subroutine template (if it doesn't already exist) and open it for editing.

Comment: You were correct daShier - I was processing the code in the wrong handler.  I put the code, as you suggested, in the _CheckChanged handler of each of the three check boxes and "Ta-Da" it worked perfectly.  If I chose check box 1 and then went to checkbox2 and chose it then the check in checkbox1 went away and the check remained in checkbox2.  Likewise with checkbox3.  Thank you so much.

Comment: I also added three radio buttons to test them out and - as you stated - they do that automatically without adding any code.  However, since the checkboxes worked perfectly, I deleted the radio buttons.  Again, Thank you for your time and knowledge.  Is there a place here where I can give you a rating?

Comment: If my answer helped, simply check it off and that adds to my reputation here.